# What's the proper way to store and retrieve Application settings?

Tags: c#, settings, storage, appsettings

I'm predominantly a C# .NET 4.0 developer, and right now I'm reconsidering past approaches to storing and retrieving application settings.

In the past I've used a variety of methods, from simple 'flat' text files with tab separated key/values, to layered XML files, and a few other things in between. I've used in the past ( and am considering using again ) the built in App.Config/AppSettings classes, but there isn't any built in way to save data that you've loaded in from this source ( I could go into the difficulties I'm having in doing this but that's not the point of the question ).

The point here, is that all of these methods have their shortcomings, and while some work better than others, some are simpler to employ than others, and I am trying to nail down something that will be consistent and reliable.

My question, which will likely have a few valid answers so I'll be forced to pick the best one, is this: What if any built-in framework would 'you' recommend for both saving and loading data in and out of a settings file that can accompany the executable, or if not a built in framework, what standard would you recommend? XML? 'Flat' files? Stand-Alone Database?

Assume that the configuration itself won't be that large, and any real quantity of data will be read from a database ( or using some other technology ).

Comment: good question but I think it's very personal I love kernel32 WritePrivateProfileString and I have strong opinion that nothing can beat it in simplicity stability and speed, I can provide interface for C# if you like [yes, I'm NOT voting to close]

Comment: While this does have some merit as a question, you've suggested yourself that there's no "right" answer.  I'm also not clear on what the problem is that you have with the `app.config` approach (surely you *do* save data that you load in back to `app.config`?).  Can you expand on that?

Comment: Sure Dan; the problem I am experiencing right now, is that my AppSettings dictionary is ReadOnly, and as a result I cannot remove/add items out/back in. The only way I can consider that I can go about saving my app settings back to the file, is by re-writing the entire file, which I'm not particularly hot on pursuing. There is no 'right' answer because this is a matter of opinions as to what is the 'best' solution, but there are quite a few potentially 'valid' answers. I'm simply looking for the most reliable, full featured method to perform the task. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Im a registry fan, and would rather have my settings there, with my c# apps I've used the settings that come built in - so under project properties you can define a load, and their default values, and then access them with

```
Properties.Settings.Default.<settingname>
```

and can set them too, so `Properties.Settings.Default.HideDisabled = true;`

and you can save them with

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Ive not had issues with this, but then, as you said, everything has a pro and a con.

Comment: This is by far the best and most convenient way to store user settings, IMHO.

Comment: (Can't edit my previous comment) I meant to say Application settings, not user settings, of course.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable method to pursue, but one that I have not used in the past. I wonder if you could point me at a 'Hello World' or some such for employing this?

Comment: Nevermind; figured it out. I'll give this a try for my current project. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Was gonna say, as said: Project properties, setup the ones you want, Ive shown how to read them, how to set them and how to save them :) Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Just yet another way (kernel32), it's not much about C# even C# 4.0 but as we have started list of variants it must be valid here

```
namespace Ini {
    public class IniFile {
        private string path;
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
            string key, string val, string filePath);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
                    string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
            int size, string filePath);
        public IniFile(string INIPath) {
            path = INIPath;
            }
        public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, string Value) {
            WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
            }
        public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key) {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp,
                                            255, this.path);
            return temp.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A few applications I've worked on involve local databases and we used that database file to hold our settings too. It works, but something it just feels kinda wrong and it can be a problem if you would like to be able to modify a setting when your application is not running. (To bypass a crash or something alike.)

Most often I will just use an XML file stored in the `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` folder and use a `DataContractSerializer`. It allows you to do some versioning, but most importantly, it's able to load and save XML files when certain properties on your settings object are new or non-existing. It won't crash the application and when you save your settings again it'll just save the latest version. I think it's clean, mean and simple.